# Reboot server in Intellij Idea

Tags: intellij-idea, server

When one opens `.html` file with the help of Intellij Idea, IDE creates server for that one. But what if I need to restart the server. Is it possible? How to do that?

Comment: For html, JS file changes, just reloading is enough. Why you need a restart??

Comment: Built-in web server is created once on IDE start, you can't restart it without restarting IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: @CrazyCoder, it is exactly what I was asking for. Thanks.

Comment: @SupunWijerathne, because Idea decides for me which files to take, if those files have same names.

Comment: @PratikAmbani, Idea starts server, I want to reboot it. It seems to me my question is clear. If you suppose that I meant something else you are wrong. I meant exactly what I wrote.